# Unable to link to shared library

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, linker, shared-libraries

I'm building a shared library with g++ 3.3.4. I cannot link to the library because I am getting

```
./BcdFile.RHEL70.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt8_Rb_treeIjjSt9_IdentityIjESt4lessIjESaIjEE13insert_uniqueERKj
```

Which c++filt describes as

```
std::_Rb_tree<unsigned int, unsigned int, std::_Identity<unsigned int>, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::insert_unique(unsigned int const&)
```

I thought this might have come from using hash_map, but I've taken that all out and switched to regular std::map. I am using g++ to do the linking, which is including `-lstdc++`.

Does anyone know what class would be instantiating this template? Or even better, which library I need to be linking to?

*EDIT:* After further review, it appears adding the -frepo flag when compiling has caused this, unfortunately that flag is working around gcc3.3 bug.

Comment: So, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

`std::_Rb_Tree` might be a red-black tree, which would most likely be from using `map`. It should be part of `libstdc++`, unless your library is linking against a different version of `libstdc++` than the application, which from what you've said so far seems unlikely.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the red-black tree is the underlying data structure in `map`. All that `hash_map` does is hash the key before using it, rather than using the raw value.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#include < map >
```

in the source file where you are using map.

Comment: A missing #include would cause a compile time error, not a link time error.

Comment: I had a very similar error once.  Adding #include < map >, even though it was a part of another include, fixed it.  I never figured out what it was.  Must have been a problem with instantiation of std::map.  In general you're right.  But with templates, you can get all sorts of weird errors.

Comment: Bumped back up. Could indeed be the problem, as <map> and <set> usually include other headers. std::map<> might very well be declared in a base header shared with <set>, then defined in <map>. So, you'd get only std::map declarations if you'd include just <set>. (Could - depends on compiler)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have 2 different incompatible versions of libstdc++.so from different versions of gcc. Check your paths.